# Domain objects presentation properties

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

Let's say in my domain I have a `Money(amount, Currency(name))` value object (for example: `new Money(1000, new Currency('USD'))`).
However in my presentation layer (and only there really) I don't want to use `USD` currency name, but symbol (`$`) instead.
I don't want to overload my value object with presentation properties (since besides symbol there can be also such things as placement).

How do you guys handle this kind of mappings? Should I create some kind of `CurrencyPropertyInMemoryRepository` and fetch all info from there? What are my options?

Comment: Regardless of language, I'd have a UI helper (a widget) for presenting the value object. In C# I'd use an extension method.

Comment: Like MikeSW said, if it's a UI concern then it should be handled within the UI. You could have a map of currency/symbol key/value.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern that you want to separate this presentation aspect from your domain data, and if you want to go that way, I think using a repository for mapping the currency name to its symbol might be a good solution (retrieving the correct symbol could then be done in a `ValueConverter` for example that transforms your model data before they are presented in your UI).

But I personally would not have an issue by storing this additional symbol information also in the currency value object, for two reasons:

1. The currency symbol is highly related to the currency itself, so whenever the currency name changes, the symbol might also change. Therefore it would make sense to have both information stored in the same place or at least quite close to each other. When using an additional repository, your information is spread at least over two places.
2. If you have both information within your value object, you could also put additional behavior in your value object (e.g. not every currency has a symbol, in that case you need some logic to decide what to print instead).